# Is there a way to tidy up a dictionary when printing it

Tags: python, dictionary

I don't know whether the question is a little weird or not, but I am working on a scrip that counts the number of lines (alter words and duplicates) in all text files in a given directory.

Then it puts the results into a dictionary with file being the key and number of lines being the value. I would like to print the dictionary like this:

```
file name: number of lines
file name2: number of lines2
```

instead of:

```
{'file directory':'number of lines','file directory2':'number of lines2'}
```

Also, is there a way to delete the repetitive beginning of the directory and be left just with the file name?

Comment: You should keep your questions to one issue at a time; the 'repetitive beginning' part is a different question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This question seems to me to be primarily a formatting question, and the "repetitive beginning" thing (despite being a string-parsing issue from an implementation standpoint) is part of the formatting.

Comment: @KyleStrand Yeah, its all to do with the same dictionary so I thought it'd be relevant

Comment: Also, if you ever just want a convenient way to easily see what's in a dictionary (i.e. you don't need very nice formatting), I'd recommend `pprint.pprint(<dictionary>)` (using the `pprint` module).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just loop over your dictionary and print the contents then:

```
for path, num in dictionary.iteritems():
    filename = os.path.basename(path)
    print '{}: {}'.format(filename, num)
```

If you are using Python 3, use `dictionary.items()` and `print()` as a function rather than as a statement.

Use `os.path.basename()` to extract the base filename from a path.

Comment: +1 I think that he doesn't want to print the "file" part of the key, probably should switch `filename` with `filename.split()[1:]` or something like that

Comment: @alfasin: there are two separate issues there, really. 1) how to print the dictionary contents differently and 2) how to get the base name from a path. For the latter you use `os.path.basename()`, not `filename.split()[1]`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I thought it is part of the same question because these are all modifications to the same dictionary

Comment: @Sebastian: fair enough, merged the two parts into one example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've figured it out from the first response anyway, Thank you very much :) Second time today you helped me out... quite active aren't you